# Irrlicht en Linux: Referencia a createDevice sin definir

Tags: c++, enlazado

Estoy intentando retomar mis experimentos con Irrlicht, un motor 3D. Recuerdo que en su día no tuve problemas, pero ahora ... se me está *atascando*.

En el archivo de cabecera (`irrlicht/irrlicht.h`) hay una definición de función:

```
...
namespace irr
{
    extern "C" IRRLICHT_API IrrlichtDevice* IRRCALLCONV createDevice(
        video::E_DRIVER_TYPE deviceType = video::EDT_SOFTWARE,
        const core::dimension2d<u32>& windowSize = (core::dimension2d<u32>(640,480)),
        u32 bits = 16,
        bool fullscreen = false,
        bool stencilbuffer = false,
        bool vsync = false,
        IEventReceiver* receiver = 0);

...
```

La librería dinámica `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIrrlicht.so.1.8` **exporta** esa función, pero **fuera** del `namespace irr`:

> >nm -gDC libIrrlicht.so.1.8
> ...
>     000000000044d750 T createDevice
> ...
>     000000000044d5c0 W irr::COSOperator::~COSOperator()
> ...

Se ve claramente que la definición está **fuera** de ningún `namespace`. Y, según [el manual de `nm`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nm.1.html), los símbolos de tipo `T` están definidos en la sección `.text` del archivo. Entiendo que dicha función **si** existe en la propia librería.

Sin embargo, si intento compilar uno de los propios ejemplos que aparecen en la documentación del motor:

```
#include <irrlicht/irrlicht.h>

using namespace irr;

using namespace core;
using namespace scene;
using namespace video;
using namespace io;
using namespace gui;

int main( ) {
    auto device = createDevice( video::EDT_SOFTWARE, dimension2d< u32 >( 640, 480 ), 16, false, false, false, 0 );

    return 0;
}
```

> g++ --std=c++17 -lIrrlicht -o hello hello.cpp
>     /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc5ElqSF.o: en la función 'main':
>     hello.cpp:(.text+0x6c): referencia a 'createDevice' sin definir

He intento añadir mi propia definición de la función problemática **fuera** del `namespace irr`:

```
...

extern "C" {

IRRLICHT_API irr::IrrlichtDevice* IRRCALLCONV createDevice(
    irr::video::E_DRIVER_TYPE deviceType = irr::video::EDT_SOFTWARE,
    const irr::core::dimension2d< irr::u32 > &windowSize = (irr::core::dimension2d< irr::u32 >( 640, 480 ) ),
    irr::u32 bits = 16,
    bool fullscreen = false,
    bool stencilbuffer = false,
    bool vsync = false,
    irr::IEventReceiver* receiver = 0 );

}

int main( ) {
    auto device = ::createDevice( video::EDT_SOFTWARE, dimension2d< u32 >( 640, 480 ), 16, false, false, false, 0 );

    return 0;
}
```

Además del anterior, también he hecho otros intentos, añadiendo mi definición de `createDevice` antes de los `using`, por si el compilador se lia con las búsquedas. Desafortunadamente, el compilador insiste testarudamente en ignorar mis esfuerzos y seguir mostrando el *errorcito* de marras: `referencia a createDevice sin definir`.

- ¿ Qué estoy haciendo mal ?
- ¿ Cómo lo soluciono ?

Por aclarar, estoy usando:

> >g++ --version
> g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
> >dpkg -l libirrlicht1.8
> libirrlicht1.8:amd64 1.8.5+ds-2   amd64

Comment: He probado el ejemplo por curiosidad en Arch (misma versión de irrlicht, solo que con g++ 13.2.1), compila y se ejecuta sin problemas... ¿qué te muestra `ldconfig -p | grep "libIrrlicht"`?

Comment: @FJSevilla Muestra lo esperado: `libIrrlicht.so.1.8 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIrrlicht.so.1.8 - libIrrlicht.so (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIrrlicht.so`. En el FS, el segundo es un enlace simbólico al primero, y el primero un enlace simbólico a `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIrrlicht.so.1.8.5`. Todos son los instalados por el paquete `libirrlicht1.8`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece ser que se trata simplemente del orden en el que le pasas los parámetros a `gcc` simplemente con:

```
  # g++ --std=c++17 -o test test.cpp -lIrrlicht
```

Compila perfectamente, pero si ejecuto

```
  # g++ --std=c++17 -lIrrlicht -o hello test.cpp 
  /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccUD8TZ6.o: in function `main': test.cpp:(.text+0x69): undefined
  reference to `createDevice' 
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Al parecer el orden en el que pasamos los parámetros al linker importa (ejecuta las cosas en orden). Como norma general, las librerías siempre van al final de la línea de comandos.

Para dar un poco más de valor a la respuesta incluimos la forma en la que hemos reproducido tu mismo entorno utilizando `docker`. Los comandos que utilizamos son los siguientes:

```
$ docker run --rm -it -v $PWD/code/:/opt/code --name SOES ubuntu:22.04
```

Esto inicializa un contenedor con Ubuntu 22.04 en modo interactivo `-it`, eliminando el contenedor al salir de la sesión (`--rm`) y montando el subdirectorio `code` en el directorio actual del host en `/opt/code` dentro del contenedor, de forma que podemos editar cómodamente nuestros ficheros fuente en el host.

Una vez en el contenedor:

```
  root@f21d4e429ab9:/# apt update
  (....)
  root@f21d4e429ab9:/# apt upgrade
  (....)
  root@f21d4e429ab9:/# apt install build-essential libirrlicht-dev
  (...)
  root@f21d4e429ab9:/# cd /opt/code
  root@f21d4e429ab9:/opt/code# g++ --version
  g++ (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0
  (...)
  root@f21d4e429ab9:/opt/code# dpkg -l libirrlicht1.8
  (...)
  ii  libirrlicht1.8:amd64 1.8.5+ds-2   amd64        High performance realtime 3D engine
  root@f21d4e429ab9:/opt/code# g++ --std=c++17 -lIrrlicht -o hello test.cpp
  /usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccUD8TZ6.o: in function `main':
  test.cpp:(.text+0x69): undefined reference to `createDevice'
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  root@f21d4e429ab9:/opt/code# g++ --std=c++17 -o test test.cpp -lIrrlicht
  root@f21d4e429ab9:/opt/code#
```